# MVC Object(x) does not contain a definition for blah

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Getting an error on the view, at the displaynamefor softwareid line, saying the model SoftwareDTO does not contain a definition for softwareid.  I can see it right there in the model.

Model:

```
public class SoftwareDTO
{
    public int SoftwareId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<SoftwareDTO> softwareList = new List<SoftwareDTO>();
        var data = _db.Software.ToList();

        foreach (var sw in data)
        {
            SoftwareDTO software = new SoftwareDTO()
            {
                SoftwareId = sw.SoftwareId,
                Name = sw.Name,
                Description = sw.Description
            };
            softwareList.Add(software);
        };

        return View(softwareList);
    }
```

View:

```
@model List<Request.Models.SoftwareDTO>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SoftwareId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SoftwareId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
```

Comment: Your model is a `List<SoftwareDTO>`, not `SoftwareDTO`.

Answer (score 0):

**its because model its a list not an object SoftwareDTO  in your razor view**
I think you are missing the foreach

Answer (score 0):

`SoftwareId` is a property of `SoftwareDTO` class. Your view is strongly typed to a collection of SoftwareDTO objects. So you need to loop through the model(*The collection of SoftwareDTO*) and access the `SoftwareId` of each item.

```
@model List<Request.Models.SoftwareDTO>

<table class="table">
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   <tr>
      <td>
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(x=> item.SoftwareId)
      </td>
   </tr>
}
</table>
```

**EDIT :** *As per the edit in the question, and the comments provided.*

Looks like you want to print the display name of the propertes in your table headers. If you do not wish to change the data you are passing from your action method, you can try this

```
@if (Model.Any())
{
   <table class="table">
      <tr>
          <th>
              @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => Model[0].SoftwareId)
          </th>
      </tr>
      @foreach (var item in Model)
      {
          <tr>
              <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.SoftwareId)
               </td>
          </tr>
      }
   </table>
}
```

This is using the first item in the collection and it's properties to use with `DisplayNameFor` method. Since i have a if condition to check for at least one item before rendering the table, It will not even  render the table if your Model has 0 items.

If you want to show the empty table with headers, you have 2 options.

**Write HTML markup for the table header**

```
  <table class="table">
      <tr>
            <th>
               <label>Software Id</label>
            </th>
      </tr>
      @foreach (var item in Model)
      {
         <tr>
             <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.SoftwareId)
              </td>
         </tr>
        }
  </table>
```

Or if you still want to use the `DisplayNameFor` helper method to render the table header labels,
**Create a new viewmodel**

```
public class TableListVm
{
  public List<SoftwareDTO> Items {set;get;}
  public SoftwareDto ItemMeta {set;get;}
  public TableListVm()
  {
     ItemMeta= new SoftwareDto();
  }    
}
```

And in your GET action, Send this object to your view

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var data = _db.Software.ToList().Select(sw=> new SoftwareDTO { 
                      SoftwareId = sw.SoftwareId,
                      Name = sw.Name,
                      Description = sw.Description
                     }).ToList();
  var vm= new TableListVm { Items = data };
  return View(vm);
}
```

And in your view which is strongly typed to this new view model.

```
@model TableListVm
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => Model.ItemMeta.SoftwareId)
         </th>
     </tr>
     @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
      {
         <tr>
             <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.SoftwareId)
              </td>
         </tr>
       }
 </table>
```

Comment: This is a scaffolded view from Visual Studio (I didnt write it), are you saying the scaffold is wrong?

Comment: Your error says something is wrong ! So i guess you should try the answer and see whether that solves the problem. But you definitely need a loop on your Model, which is a collection to access each item's properties. Go ahead and try the solution. Now about whether scaffolding is creating something wrong or right, I don't know. :)

Comment: I apologize for ruffling your rainbow brite tail. Putting the header row in a foreach didn't work, which it shouldn't because it is a table header and only displayed once.  If I hard code the header row, it works.  So not sure what the deal is.